# Inference script, separate load model and prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have an inference script where the load model and prediction are in one script, how to separate them so i do not have to load the model every time i have to make a prediction

```
from keras.models import load_model

# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')

# prediction
result = model.predict(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

keep the model as a global variable and predict as a function inside this module.

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = None
# load model
def load_model_weights():
    model = load_model('model.h5')

def predict(image):
    if(model is None):
        load_model_weights()
    else:
        # prediction
        result = model.predict(image)
    return result
```

import the function predict from this module and use it in other modules.